# Create selectlist from list from another list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, selectlist

I have two different models. A UsersInRoles model and a Users model.  Users can be in multiple roles, so in the UsersInRoles model it matches a userId with a RoleId.  What I need to do is get a selectList for all users in a particular role.  I have tried two different methods which both are not working.

Here is the first method I tried:

```
var techs = new HashSet<Guid>(db.usersInRoles.Where(u => u.RoleId == new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.TechID)).Select(u => u.UserId));
ViewBag.SearchTechnician = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == techs.Contains<userId>).OrderBy(u => u.FirstName).ThenBy(u => u.LastName), "FullName", "FullName");
```

and I am getting an error on the .Contains that says:

> The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?

The second method I have tried is:

```
ViewBag.SearchTechnician = new SelectList(from u in db.Users
                                          where u.UserId = (
                                          from ur in db.usersInRoles
                                          where ur.RoleId = new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.TechID)
                                          select ur.UserId
                                          );
```

and I am receiving an error on the second where clause saying the following:

cannot implicitly convert type System.Guid to bool

Am I on the right track or I am completely down the wrong path?

Comment: You need to use == to make a comparison in second code snippet you posted.

Comment: Replace `=` with `==`: `where ur.RoleId == new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.TechID`. Also `Contains<userId>` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use == instead of = to make comparison in second approach you used.

```
where ur.RoleId == new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.TechID)
```